# Alternative phrases for the phrase "Ace in the hole"

Tags: phrase-request

I heard the phrase "ace in the hole" in a podcast; it is a weapon for which there is no defense.

Could somebody suggest alternative idiomatic phrases for "ace in the hole", which have the same ring/wittiness (for the lack of a better word), which native English speakers use in everyday conversations.

Context,

> When the debate got heated, John used his ace in the hole against Jane, that Jane was in jail for fraud, and has no credibility.

Answer (score 1):

One might use:

> John used his *sure advantage/advantage* against Jane